# pandas groupby and aggregate into new column

Tags: python, pandas

did some searching but nothing yields the desired result, which is grouping the data by date and counting the frequency. I am able to do this with aggregate but I'm not sure how to create a new column with the results, thanks.

data in file:

```
Domain  Dates
twitter.com 2016-08-08
google.com  2016-08-09
apple.com   2016-08-09
linkedin.com    2016-08-09
microsoft.com   2016-08-09
slack.com   2016-08-12
instagram.com   2016-08-12
ibm.com 2016-08-12
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('domains.tsv', sep='\t')
df = df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df.Dates).dt.date]).agg({'Dates':'size'})
print(df)
```

yields

```
            Dates
Dates
2016-08-08      1
2016-08-09      4
2016-08-12      3
```

Ideally, I would like the count column to be 'count' and then I will save as a new csv.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Are you asking how to re-name a column?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't realize there were two columns both with 'Dates', I thought it was just outputting that response because the column didn't have a name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('domains.tsv', sep='\t')
counter = df.groupby('Dates').count().rename(columns={'Domain': 'count'})
counter.to_csv('count.csv')
```

You will get count.csv including following result on your current dir.

```
Dates,count
2016-08-08,1
2016-08-09,4
2016-08-12,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['Dates']).transform('count')
```

Comment: See, at first this is what I thought OP wanted. Now I'm not sure.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think he was confused on that what he was actually outputting was already the counts.

Comment: @A.Kot that is yielding a different result, I think I was confused by the two columns both named 'Dates' in the output